# Nhibernate Dictionary<Entity, ? > Entity.ID Hashcode issue

Tags: c#, nhibernate, dictionary

I have the following Entities:

```
public class Entity1 
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return ID.GetHashCode();
    }
}

public class Entity2
{
    public Dictionary<Entity1,int> Dict { get; set; }
}
```

I am overriding Entity1's GetHashCode to reflect it's ID because it's the most immutable property it has, and not leaving it by reference because i have multiple sessions running and the dictionary needs to be "session" safe.

for this discussion i have an int value in the dictionary, the value is not really relevant.

Both entities are mapped correctly using NHibernate.

Lets say i have this code:

```
using (var session = GetSession())
{
    var entity1 = new Entity1();
    var entity2 = new Entity2();
    entity2.Dict[entity1] = 1;
    session.SaveOrUpdate(entity1);
    session.SaveOrUpdate(entity2);
}
```

In this code Dict will not save any key,values - because when adding entity1 into Dict before saving will give it a hashcode for null ID, which right after the hashcode will change on save with the actual ID, breaking the dictionary.

I am looking for the best practice/ best solution.

My current options :

- keeping this in mind always saving Entity1 before adding it to any Dictionaries (I have a bunch).
  I don't like this option because it's really not fool proof, and i am sure someone else later on will not pay attention to that and create horrible bugs.
- before saving - always reiterate through the key,value collection, saving the keys, and reiserting them to the dictionary, this solution seems really lacking in performance, and cause all kinds of different issues. but more than all - it sounds like there should be a better solution.

What is the best way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my project, we do the Id generation ourselves:

```
private int _id = -1;
public virtual Id
{
    get {return _id == -1? (_id = IdGenerator.GenerateNextId()): _id;}
    protected set {_id = value;}
}
```

The IdGenerator is an implementation of HiLo (TableHiLo or SequenceHiLo). Then map all entities using `assigned` id generation strategy:

```
<id name="Id" column="ID">
  <generator class="assigned" />
</id>
```

In this arrangement, all object will have an unique ID when the Id property is accessed, and that Id will never change. This solution has served me well for three years without any complication. However, convert an existing system might be complex.

I came up with this after reading this article:
[Don't Let Hibernate Steal Your Identity](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/09/13/dont-let-hibernate-steal-your-identity.html)

Edit:

There are two options to detect unsaved objects. One is using a version property. However, not all entity need such a property, so I employ an interceptor to track the transient status of entity:

```
public interface ITransienceAware
{
    bool IsTransient {get; set;}
}
```

The base class of all entities implements this interface explicitly (to hide IsTransient property from view, avoid silly mistake, as one need to cast object to ITransienceAware to change value):

```
public abstract class MappedEntity: ITransienceAware // and some more unrelated interface
{
    //...................unrelated code
    bool ITransienceAware.IsTransient { get; set; }
    //...................unrelated code
}
```

The interceptor OnLoad, OnSave methods change IsTransient to true.

Another important implementation detail is the IdGenerator: it is an implementation of TableHiLo for Sql Server and SequenceHiLo for Oracle, and it must access database in separated transaction to prevent locking across requests.

Comment: That's a valid solution, it's a new system so the change would be minor. how would NH know if an object is new or not if you set it to assigned?

Comment: where can i find a HiLo Impl?

Comment: I have added some important information about my solution. Sorry for forgot these things.